# How can i check if a record exists using simple.data and c#

Tags: c#, simple.data

Problem: I have to check whether or not a record exists in a `join` and if not ignore that user but still load all the other information for that user

```
var db = Simple.Data.Database.OpenNamedConnection("sqlConn");  
02   
03 var expr1 = db.PON_APP_USERS.STATUS == 1;  
04   
05 var sUsers = db.PON_APP_USERS.FindAll(expr1)  
06 .Select(  
07     db.PON_APP_USERS.USERKEY,  
08     db.PON_APP_USERS.LAST_NAME,  
09     db.PON_APP_USERS.FIRST_NAME,  
10     db.PON_APP_USERS.AGENCY,  
11     db.PON_APP_USERS.USERUSERS.CBI_NO,  
12     db.PON_APP_USERS.USERUSERS.EXPRNC_STAT_IN,  
13     db.PON_APP_USERS.USERUSERS.TEST_STAT_IN,  
14     db.PON_APP_USERS.USERUSERS.TWO_WKS_TRNG_DT)  
15 .LeftJoin(db.USERUSERS, USERKEY: db.PON_APP_USERS.USERKEY);
```

I'm new to simple data as in, 2 days new. So if you don't mind showing me step by step it would be greatly appreciated. This is what they are requesting of that `join`:

> /// If no record is join with the above statement, page will crash.
>   Please make adjustments to allow the page to load if the user does not
>   have a record in USERUSERS table.

Comment: Why don't you just use an IF statement? Say IF whatever criteria is null then load the rest. Or count the records it returns base if off that.

Comment: There is nothing in that code that will cause an error in Simple.Data itself. It may be that you are trying to access one of the values from the `USERUSERS` table without first checking to see if it is null?

Comment: thanks mark-- I had forgot to include a null check for userkey